# Python Module pdftotext : read_all( ) method Not Available

Tags: python, pdftotext

I am using python module **pdftotext** to read in pdf files.

```
import pdftotext

with open("lorem_ipsum.pdf", "rb") as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

# Iterate over all the pages
for page in pdf:
    print(page)

# Just read the second page
print(pdf.read(2))

# Or read all the text at once
print(pdf.read_all())
```

Above is the minimal reproducible examples, however, in my usage, there's no available methods in pdftotext.PDF such as read_all( ) or read( )

```
with open("/Users/zachary/Downloads/{}R.pdf".format(i), "rb") as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

pdf.read_all()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-4676e6ace396> in <module>()
      2     pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)
      3 
----> 4 pdf.read_all()

AttributeError: 'pdftotext.PDF' object has no attribute 'read_all'
```

What is the problem?

p.s:What I can only do with pdf instance is,

pdf[page_numb] which reads each page. It works well!

Comment: can you share the ouput for `pip show pdftotext` basically this will tell which library you are using. Also `dir(object)` will tell you all the available methods on the `object`

Comment: might want to look at this: https://github.com/jalan/pdftotext. `print("\n\n".join(pdf))` seems to be what you want

Answer (score -1):

What you can do to run pdftotext is the following:

```
from subprocess import run

filePath = "lorem_ipsum.pdf"

textCmdResult = run([ 'pdftotext', filePath, '-' ], stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
text = textCmdResult.stdout
```

This will run pdftotext as a separate process and store the results to a variable called text.

There may be other ways of making it work, but this is actually the one that got me on track.

Hope my answer was helpful,

Israel

Answer (score -1):

```py
import pdftext
with open("lorem_ipsum.pdf", "rb") as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

# Iterate over all the pages
for page in pdf:
    print(page)

# Just read the second page
print(pdf[2])
```